# Is there some method/function to pause python without stopping the current execution?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I'm trying to record streaming data from an external source in Python3.5. But when I do the following:

```
 enable_streaming()
 time.sleep(10)
 stop_streaming()
```

It appears that the streaming functionality becomes enabled, python stops for 10 seconds, then streaming is stopped. Possibly, due to python stopping for 10 seconds due to functionality of time.sleep, no streaming data is actually recorded. I used wireshark to track the flow to data and it seems that the destination acknowledges that enable_streaming() is received.

Enable_streaming() is a function called from a dll. 
The dll works in matlab so that leads me to believe that python's time.sleep() is the issue here.
I don't have access to the source code of the dll but due to it working in Matlab and it's just a simple return ctypes function, I have to assume the dll is correct and not the issue here.

The python code calling enable streaming is:

```
import ctypes as ct
shim = ct.cdll.LoadLibrary('PCdll')

def enable_streaming()
    f = shim.enable_streaming
    f.restype = ct.c_int #return is int
    result = f()
```

So my question is: is there some sort of command in python that pauses but doesn't "suspend execution of the current thread" like time.sleep() does?

Attempted with no success. Seems like this isn't the issue:

```
import time
start = time.time()

enable_streaming()
while (time.time() - start < 10): # 10 seconds
    pass # loop for 10 seconds

stop_streaming()
```

Comment: Yes. Sleeping blocks python. You need to do your streaming in a thread.

Comment: This is going to depend on what `enable_streaming` is and how it works. If it were operating in its own thread, that `time.sleep` would have worked. If it's in your thread, there's something you'll have to do to actually operate this functionality. You can't just "pause without stopping".

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to do?

Comment: What would be the point of sleeping if it did not suspend execution?

Comment: Show us the Matlab code.

Comment: Falmarri, can you direct me on how to do this? I'd imagine the thread created is within the dll. I know that the port is chosen dynamically within the dll

Comment: user2357112 Unfortunately I don't have access to that currently. I have access to the labview code which works as well though. But I can't post a block diagram on stackoverflow i think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will fix it, as it doesn't seem like the streaming can do anything without a thread, but this is what I usually do when I need to do something for a certain period of time without blocking.

```
import time

start = time.time()

while (time.time() - start < 10): # 10 seconds
    # loop for 10 seconds
```

Comment: This didn't solve my issue but it did rule out that time.sleep() was the issue. Thank you